# Drupal 7 hook_menu() throws a 404

Tags: ajax, post, drupal, drupal-7, hook-menu

I have tried to acces it through an ajax call and by simply going to it by url,
It always give me a 404

i have flushed my caches multiple times and even tried to remove and re-add the module (as i have had the problem with other modules and read on other responses on the problem)

i also have looked it up on internet, but i can't seem to find any solution
(module name : TTK_rest)

.module:

```
function TTK_rest_menu() {  
    $items = array();
    $items['TTK_rest_api/TTK_task_progression'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'TTK_task_progression_view',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function TTK_task_progression_view(){

    return '{"pom":"pom"}';
}
```

and the ajax call to it:

```
$.ajax({                 
                url:'/TTK_rest_api/TTK_task_progression',                   
                data: {"getProgress": "true"},//, "event_id":settings['TTK_task_progression']['jsEvent_id']
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "JSON",
                success: function(data){
                    var $data = $(data);
                    console.log(data);




                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log("neupe, try again");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the solution (posted the question after multiple hours of searching, if i've known i would have find an answer this quick i wouldn't have asked it.. still going to leave it up with a response in case there is someone with the same problem

solution to the problem was that i had to have my function name had to have the module name prefix

**note**: i have an other module called 'TTK_task_progression', might be the origin of the problem i had

solution:

```
function TTK_rest_menu() {  
    $items = array();
    $items['TTK_rest_api/TTK_task_progression'] = array(
        'page callback' => 'TTK_rest_progression', // <- changed
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function TTK_rest_progression(){ // <- changed

    return '{"pom":"pom"}';
}
```

Comment: That isn't what fixed it, the function name is arbitrary (so long as its unique). More likely you didn't clear the cache

Comment: as i said, if you had taken the time to read the post, i have flushed my cash multiple times and even tried to delete and recopy the whole module, both of these did not fix my problem.

Comment: Maybe I missed it because you spelled it wrong. Either way, this answer didn't fix the issue in the question, unless you have a non-standard version of core

Comment: i also do have a second module which is called TTK_task_progression, could it be possible they were in conflict because of the same prefix?

Comment: deleted my previous comment because it was unreadable (forgot comments had no new lines)::
Maybe english isn't my primary language? And maybe do typo's can happen? 
Either way this fixed it for me, it was the only thing i changed and it worked. As far as i now i do run standard core (version 7.42). 
The only reason i continue to respond is so maybe if someone has another solution maybe he/she will be willing to post it. Simply saying that the answer "doen't" work, isn't helping anybody.